# Non Geographic and Special Postcodes

Tags: data-request, uk, postal-code

I originally asked this on the [Stack GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) - incorrectly

I'm trying to get a list of special (those receive an exceptionally large amount of mail) and non-geographic postcodes (eg PO boxes).

There's nothing definitive available on [ONS](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/) or [OS](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/search) that I can find.

The ONS postcode lookup provides a lookup against Grid Ref positional quality indicator but this isn't definitive. eg PO Boxes are assigned an `osind` of 6 but so are other things.  So this doesn't work for me.

Other than this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Non-geographic_codes) I can't find anything.

Comment: Have you looked at the usertype field in the ONS Postcode Directory? Large users are often large organisations. You could also match postcode coordinates against the coordinates of the sorting offices. From the docs: "Non-geographic postcodes can either be special postcodes assigned to some large users of the postal service or PO Boxes that lie within a (pseudo) postcode district that does not form a discrete part of a post town. These will all have been assigned a grid reference, usually the local Royal Mail sorting office".

Comment: Special postcodes are assigned to organisations which who receive an exceptionally large amount of mail which is a lot more than a "normal" large organisations. So that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I found a list from 2012 in PDF format via the [IanVisits](https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/articles/londons-non-geographic-postcodes-38692/) website:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120916141140/http://www.poweredbypaf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/12July_current_non-geos-original.pdf